# Standard way to specify filename with HTTP PUT

Tags: http

With HTTP PUT requests, is it typical for the filename to be included as part of the request URI such as:

```
http://host/myfilename.txt
```

or is it included as a standard header key/value pair? If so, what is the key?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is not the key values pair but the complete URI. Which means it will direct you to the resource completely. It is the standard. [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) is where you will go through to understand how URIs are represented.

Answer (score 3):

If you expect to be able to issue `GET /myfilename.txt`, then it is appropriate to `PUT /myfilename.txt`.  However, if the server is going to place the file under a different resource, then you should probably use `POST /some/server/resource` and return a `Location` header for the newly created resource that can be used to retrieve the file from.

Answer (score 1):

Its standard to use the URI to tell the handling system where the file should be located. (So, the way you wrote it is correct.)